# NodeJS. Не могу реализовать пагинацию через get параметры, 404 ошибка

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express

Делаю пагинацию, но столкнулся с проблемой, кажется, запрос не видит гет параметры, как ее решить.

---

```
  // router.get("/posts", (req, res) => { // /api/posts +
  // router.get("/posts/:limit", (req, res) => { // /api/posts/3 +
  router.get("/posts?limit=:limit", (req, res) => { // /api/posts?limit=3, даже не заходит в роутер -
  console.log(req.query); // {}
  console.log(req.params); // limit: '3'
  Post.find() 
    .limit(req.query.limit) //  пробовал req.query.limit, ничего
    .then(posts => {
      res.json(posts);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

---

[image: запрос]

Comment: Очевидно, не использовать гет параметры в шаблоне роута. Чем `.get("/posts")` не устроил?

Comment: Либо `router.get("/posts/limit/:limit", (req, res) => { ...`, тогда `limit` будет в `req.params.limit`, либо `router.get("/posts", (req, res) => { ...`, и брать `limit` в `req.query.limit`.

Comment: Зачем задавать тот же вопрос второй раз?

Comment: @Yaant Спасибо, вы помогли решить мою проблему